# reduce the space between the y axes and y label in matlab

Tags: matlab, position

I would like to reduce the space between the ylabel and the y axes (the yticks).

Any idea how to "move" the ylabel a little bit to the right, i.e. changing its position horizontally?

Thanks

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611259/how-to-adjust-the-distance-between-the-y-label-and-the-y-axis-in-matlab ?

Comment: @WhiteViking Yes it does.  Closing as duplicate. Thanks for the find!