# Matlab figure, fit content

Tags: matlab, save, figure

I am using following code for plotting a figure and save it automatically! I've used same method for plenty of figures... but when using 'plotyy' function the content doesn't fit within the frame. The second ylabel seems to be outside the frame. How can I make it fit inside for automatic 'plotting, saving and closing'.

[image]

```
Cd = [1.984228000E-02   1.957250000E-02 1.809702000E-02 1.743208000E-02 1.744823000E-02 1.746511000E-02 1.749275000E-02 1.753570000E-02];
Cl = [2.589287000E-01   2.932431000E-01 2.885334000E-01 2.854248000E-01 2.858767000E-01 2.860403000E-01 2.861446000E-01 2.861447000E-01];
NC = [3616  15246   62578   253530  321328  397150  480996  572866];

h = figure(1);
hold on
[AX,H1,H2]= plotyy(NC,Cl,NC,Cd);
set(AX,{'XScale'},{'log';'log'})
set(AX,{'ycolor'},{'b';'r'})
set(H1,'Marker','o','LineStyle','--','Color','b')
set(H2,'Marker','^','LineStyle','--','Color','r')

xlabel('X AXIS')
ylabel(AX(1),'Lift')
ylabel(AX(2),'Drag')
grid on

print(h, '-dpng', 'Filename.png')
close(h)
```

Comment: You could always extend your figure canvas, e.g., `set(h,  'Position', [400, 400, 800, 400]);`.

Comment: @Marcin , Thanks for the reply... Yes, I could do something like that. But then I'd loose the consistency of figures size... which I'll be using for a scientific report.

Comment: You might find something of interest there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611259/how-to-adjust-the-distance-between-the-y-label-and-the-y-axis-in-matlab

Comment: If no other solution is provided, this might be what I'll work with. Thanks @BillBokeey